# Calculating IRR with cashflows vs NAV - getting different answers

Tags: investing, rate-of-return

I'd like to calculate an investment's IRR by looking at the NAV/share of the investment and also by looking at the cash flows as a check.  The results should be the same.

The following case works fine.  I calculate the IRR by the product of the single period returns (monthly) where the single period returns are calculated from the change in NAV.  The IRR is 7.98.  If I use Excel's XIRR function with the starting outflow and ending inflow I also get 7.98.

```
End Date       # Shares  Ending NAV/Shr Period Return  +1   IRR       Cash Flows     IRR
6/25/2014      52.537    1.82025802                                  -95.63106889      
7/25/2014      52.537    1.83192383     0.006409  1.006409                        
8/25/2014      52.537    1.84367069     0.006412  1.006412                        
9/25/2014      52.537    1.85549583     0.006414  1.006414                        
10/25/2014     52.537    1.86739956     0.006415  1.006415                        
11/25/2014     52.537    1.87938219     0.006417  1.006417                        
12/25/2014     52.537    1.89144404     0.006418  1.006418                        
1/25/2015      52.537    1.90358546     0.006419  1.006419                        
2/25/2015      52.537    1.91580681     0.006420  1.006420                        
3/25/2015      52.537    1.92810846     0.006421  1.006421                        
4/25/2015      52.537    1.94049078     0.006422  1.006422                        
5/25/2015      52.537    1.95295416     0.006423  1.006423                        
6/25/2015      52.537    1.96549902     0.006424  1.006424  7.98%     103.2616091    7.98%
```

But the next case below doesn't work.  By using the NAVs I get 6.06% and by using the cash flows I get 6.45%.  The only meaningful difference I can see in these two examples is that in this second example the number of shares held increases.

```
End Date       # Shares  Ending NAV/Shr Period Return  +1   IRR       Cash Flows     IRR
6/25/2014      8.333     1.000000                                     -8.333333      
7/25/2014      16.646    1.002457       0.002457  1.002457            -8.333333      
8/25/2014      24.926    1.006471       0.004003  1.004003            -8.333333      
9/25/2014      33.169    1.011020       0.004520  1.004520            -8.333333      
10/25/2014     41.372    1.015850       0.004778  1.004778            -8.333333      
11/25/2014     49.535    1.020862       0.004933  1.004933            -8.333333      
12/25/2014     49.535    1.026003       0.005036  1.005036            0.000000      
1/25/2015      49.535    1.031692       0.005545  1.005545            0.000000      
2/25/2015      49.535    1.037413       0.005545  1.005545            0.000000      
3/25/2015      49.535    1.043164       0.005544  1.005544            0.000000      
4/25/2015      49.535    1.048947       0.005544  1.005544            0.000000      
5/25/2015      49.535    1.054762       0.005543  1.005543            0.000000      
6/25/2015      0.000     1.060609       0.005543  1.005543  6.06%     52.537095      6.45%
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating using different methods.  For example, to obtain 6.45%

```
e = 2.71828182;
r = x /. FindRoot[8.333333 e^x +
      8.333333 e^(11/12 x) +
      8.333333 e^(10/12 x) +
      8.333333 e^(9/12 x) +
      8.333333 e^(8/12 x) +
      8.333333 e^(7/12 x) == 52.537095, {x, 0}];
100 (e^r - 1)
```

> 6.44647

This is effectively the same as the [money-weighted return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Internal_rate_of_return) calculation.

In arriving at 6.06% you have calculated the [true time-weighted return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-weighted_return).

Both answers are right, but they are different measures.

To use time-weighted returns you need to know the value of the investment at the time of every cash flow. [Modified Dietz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Dietz_method) uses a simple approximation to avoid that requirement.  Money-weighted return gives results that are more accurate for back calculating than Modified Dietz, (also without requiring interim valuations), but the calculation is more complex.

See [How to Calculate your Portfolio's Rate of Return](http://www.pwlcapital.com/pwl/media/pwl-media/PDF-files/White-Papers/How-to-Calculate-your-Portfolio-s-Rate-of-Return.pdf?ext=.pdf) for a decent reference.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Could you explain the calculation syntax in your code block please?  What is r=x/.?

Comment: @mchac - hi, that's specifically Mathematica syntax.  It just sets `r` as the solution root, `x`.  Hopefully the rest of the calculation is clear.  It's just the log form of the [money-weighted return formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Internal_rate_of_return).

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thank you again.  Last question on the above, using TWROR how is a 2 year rate interpreted? I.e. the product of 24 net monthly returns results in a 13.85% return. If I want to express the average annual return over the 2 years is it as simple as 13.85/2 since there is no compounding (so no solving for an IRR)?

Comment: @mchac - you should refer to this section on [annualisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Annualisation).  If your example is a continuation of the table in your question then it *would* seem to involve compounding, so `r = (1 + R)^(1/t) - 1 = (1 + 0.1385)^(1/2) - 1 = 0.067 = 6.7%`

Comment: Ok.  Yes, it is a continuation of the table in my question. I was thinking about this incorrectly.  It's a theoretical fund where an inv is placed on day 1 and redeemed at a future date with no intermed cashflows to the investor. But you are correct, practically, there are intermediate cashflows monthly (inc and exp and ultimately a period end value) but they are retained in the fund and that's where I went wrong.  I had calc 6.7 then thought the investor isn't getting the year 1 value to reinvest so it must be simpler but they are getting that value (cash retained). Thanks very much!

Comment: Doug, I have a followup question.  What is the correct terminology for the 6.7% calculated above that makes it clear that it is a rate applied for 2 years?  Annualized Holding Period TWROR?

Comment: Two year time-weighted return annualised (2 yr ann TWR) would suffice.